# How to read values from particular class of an Iframe using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

In my web page, I have imported an Iframe I want to read the values present in the class `cell-hover` of that iframe.

Comment: Is the iframe on your domain?

Comment: the domain in the sense?

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe page is on your domain, add an ID to that iframe, then use `contentWindow` property to access it (after iframe is loaded); like in the code from this example:

```
<iframe src='http://localhost/test.htm' id='ifrm1'></iframe>

<script>
var ifrm1 = document.getElementById('ifrm1');

//called after iframe is loaded
function testIfrm(){
  // Apply the property "contentWindow" to ifrm1 object
  //get array with all '.cell-hover' elements in iframe
  var cell_h = ifrm1.contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll('.cell-hover');
  alert(cell_h[0].innerHTML);  // Displays an Alert with content of 1st .cell-hover
}

//calls testIfrm() on ifrm1 load
ifrm1.addEventListener('load', testIfrm);
</script>
```

And `test.htm`:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cell-hover">one.</div>
<div class="cell-hover">two..</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tested it before posting, it works.

Source: http://coursesweb.net/javascript/get-modify-content-iframe_t

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Comment: That error is because the iframe content isn't loaded when that code is executed. I updated the answer. Add that code after `<iframe>` element.